# Simulate file download with WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller and I want to write a function that simulates a file download (not a real file - just something that is generated on the fly).

What I would like to do is send that api a parameter with file size and have it return a "binary" file generated on the fly.

something similar to this php code:

```
<?php
    $filesize = 20971520; // 20 Mo

    if (isset($_POST['d'])) {
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '. $filesize);

        for($i = 0 ; $i < $filesize ; $i++) {
            echo chr(255);
        }
    }
?>
```

The closest solution I found was something like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(@"path to image")); // this file stream will be closed by lower layers of web api for you once the response is completed.
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
```

I tried playing around with it and change it but had no luck.

would appriciate if someone could point me in the right direction and help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class FakeDownloadController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int size)
            {
                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                byte[] data = new byte[size];
                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/binary");
                var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                contentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "dummy","bin");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                return result;
            }
}
```

usage:

```
http://localhost:port/api/FakeDownload/?size=6543354
```

will return a ~6 MB file filled with NULL, called "dummy.bin".

Hope that helps.